# Using BEM CSS with Angular Directives

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, bem

I've been using BEM style CSS to style my angular directives and usually use replace: true to so that my Block level class can be on the "root" of the custom element. This makes it so that I can write all my CSS primarily with classes.

However, replace: true sometimes causes issues (having two ng-if, etc...) and is now marked as deprecated. So I'm starting to try to stay away from replace completely.

But now I'm having trouble applying BEM to these elements that have an actual custom tag the DOM -- now I have to use a tag name instead of a class name, which means I can't really use BEM anymore (since I'll have to use the tag name since I can't apply classes directly to my element in my template). Additionally, using modifiers on my custom element now seems impossible, as does using sibling CSS selectors.

Here's an example that hopefully will illustrate what I mean:

The directive:

```
angular.module('my.module')
  .directive('customElement', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        isSpecial: '='
      },
      template: '<div class="custom-element" ng-class="{\'custom-element--special\': isSpecial"></div>'
    };
  });
```

The CSS:

```
.custom-element {
  background-color: white;
}

.custom-element--special {
  background-color: red;
}

.custom-element--special + .custom-element--special { // this won't work without replace: true
   background-color: blue;
}
```

If I use replace: true everything works as expected (but then it comes with its own headaches).

If I don't use replace, the classes are not applied to the root custom element so the child selector doesn't work.

I could always add classes to the element in the postLink function, but that makes the template much less clear.

Does anyone have any experience using BEM with angular and using classes instead of tag names in your custom directives? What did you do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

i known it's a problem having `replace:false` for readability purpose.

The actual problem is that we need our [OOCSS](http://oocss.org/) but you are handling Angular Components with custom tags  has CSS Objects, and is not the case.

There is no practical solution for this, i won't recommend you to start adding classes on `postLink` function.

However what we are use to do is treat the custom tag as is own CSS Object besides the inner object structure. Forcing us to implement an extra CSS class for the custom tag.

```
block-context
  block-context__element 
    custom-element
```

Why doing this when `block-context__element` is a redundant' class?

- Because the rest of your BEM structure is the one you will maintain, the `custom-element` block should have meaning by it self and the `block-context__element` element is no expected to, you should abstract the CSS Objects from the directive's implementation, if you in some point start changing your html components your classes should still apply.

I hope this answer helps you